# New & Sale product list from specific categories

Tags: magento-1.8, new-products

I would like to make 2 links with containing all new (link 1) and sale (link 2) products from a specific category and it's sub categories.

For example:
I want to show all new products from the baby category (Id=3)
The category is already an anchor.

And the same with sale items (items have sale prices generated by the catalog sale rules)

How can i do that? Because magento hasn't have a category filter for this ...

I have magento 1.8.1 CE

Answer (score 1):

Here it explains step by step:
http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination/

Comment: i tried this solution .... But the category filtering doesn't work ... It shows still all new products.

Comment: $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                 ->getCollection()
                 ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => '3')))
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*');